# Sending email from spring boot aplication MailSendException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, email

Iam working with spring boot I want to send email from my spring boot application to the users who register to the application But iam getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The email configuration in properties file is

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.host= smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username= myeamil@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= password
spring.mail.port= 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable= true
spring.mail.properties.mail.auth= true
```

and this is the code in my service calss

```
     @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage=new SimpleMailMessage();

public ResponseDTO saveUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
            userRepositry.save(userDTO);
            simpleMailMessage.setFrom("myemail@gmail.com");
            simpleMailMessage.setSubject("some data");
            simpleMailMessage.setText("some data");
            mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
            simpleMailMessage.setTo(userDTO.getEmail());
            return new ResponseDTO("Registeration is done successfully..",true);

    }
```

Comment: Well you are first zending the mail and afterwards are settting the to address. You probably want to switch that around. Also your code is dangerous in a concurrent environment. If multiple users register at once, each might get the mail from another. Don’t construct the `SimpleMailMessage` once, construct it inside the method instead.

Comment: Thanks M Deinum the issue was in service class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my service class And the issue is resolved by changing the code to following.

```
 @Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage=new SimpleMailMessage();
    public ResponseDTO saveUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        userRepositry.save(userDTO);
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("myemail@gmail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(userDTO.getEmail());
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("some data");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("some data");
        mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
        return new ResponseDTO("Registeration is done successfully..",true);
     }
```

Comment: Your code is still dangerous in a concurrent situation. Don't create the `SimpleMailMessage` at the class level but rather in the method when you need it.